# Dont replace a word if it starts with INC0 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, replace

Im trying to mask acct numbers in an excel file with 6 digits and 9 digits. But the Incident number (INC098765) is also having six digits.  The following code is replacing the incident number also.

```
 `df = df.replace({ '\d{6}': '******'},regex=True)`
```

How do we exclude replacement if the word starts with "INC" ? `

Comment: What does *df* refer to?

Comment: @DarkKnight dataframe from pandas I would presume

Comment: @Flow Not tagged for pandas - hence my question.

Comment: yes its a dataframe im using to store my data

Comment: @VinothkumarNedunchezhian can we have an example o the df?

Comment: Actual : Remedy INC000023  -
Issue Description: Verint Call Recording -  Call only partially playing on 2 identified calls required for Fraud investigation for account number 100456Actual : Remedy INC000023  -
Issue Description: Verint Call Recording -  Call only partially playing on 2 identified calls required for Fraud investigation for account number ******

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **negative lookbehind** in the RegEx to require that the string "INC" does not appear directly before the 6 digits.

https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-regex/python-regex-lookbehind/

The RegEx with negative lookbehind is:

```
(?<!INC)\d{6}
```

You can see it working on your sample data here:

https://regex101.com/r/4Y12W5/1

So your code will become:

```
df = df.replace({'(?<!INC)\d{6}': '******'}, regex=True)
```

Comment: thanks mate, but its still coming as See: INC0******27